# Rails gem time_ago - how do I change the timezone to UTC +00:00 London?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timeago

I have installed the time_ago gem for Rails but when I do a post its saying posted '14 hours ago' when I only did it a few minutes ago.

I would like to set it as UTC +00:00 - London time.

In my index.html erb I have -

```
<%= timeago_tag house.created_at, :nojs => true, :limit => 1.day.ago %>
```

and in my application.rb I have -

```
class Application < Rails::Application
    config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
end
```

but its still showing up as 14/15 hours ago? I've run rake time:zone:all to get all timezones. Does anybody know where I'm going wrong? New to Rails so any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: First thing to note is that "London time" isn't the same as "UTC+00". *Right now* we're at UTC+0 in London, but come the summer, we'll be UTC+1. Do you actually want to use UTC, or London time?

Comment: Whatever London time is, thats what I would like to use?

Comment: That sounds a little odd to me, but in that case I'd suggest you might want to change the time zone configuration to the appropriate time zone name for London. (The IANA ID would be Europe/London, but I don't know what name form that's using...)

Comment: hmmm, I put in config.time_zone = 'Europe/London' and it hasn't changed

Comment: Okay. I think you'll need to wait for someone with more experience with time_ago to help. (Ideally, it shouldn't really care about time zones... something that was posted 3 hours ago was posted 3 hours ago wherever you are...)